# ubuntu nautilus problem hangs(not starting up) many time

Tags: nautilus

In 16.04 Ubuntu(unity) nautilus hangs many time.It's not opening.When i killed nautilus from task manager then its start working again.Even this problem happens on start up also.Any solution of this?